# Android Studio, Volley I do not get a JSON response

Tags: android, post, request, android-volley, response

I have build a laravel Rest API with a Jason Web Token. Now I want to make a App which sends data to the Webservice. Here I try to authentificate myself (with name email and password) at first but I do not get the token as a answer. I also do not get a error, nothing happens.

```
private void sendAndRequestResponse() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();

        jsonBody.put("name", "ida");
        jsonBody.put("email", "ida@gmail.com");
        jsonBody.put("password", "secret");

        final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        //RequestQueue initialized
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        mJsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        answer.setText(response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(mJsonRequest);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to start request queue in order to make the request call.

after

```
mRequestQueue.add(mJsonRequest);
```

add following

```
mRequestQueue.start();
```

Comment: Now I do not get a answer with the values I should get, is there any way to filter the response (I only want one spezial Value not all)

Comment: you're getting an answer in JSONObject so you need to parse that JSON object after that you'll able to get the ans